# Maven Resource Custom File Path

Tags: java, maven

Good time!

I have such a pom snippet:

```
<build>
        <resources>

            <resource>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/additional-resources</directory>
                <targetPath>targetDir</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>copied/bindings/**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>

        </resources>

        ...

</build>
```

After a compilation phase, I see such a hierarchy in the `build` directory: `targetDir/copied/bindings/test/...` which fully copies the path in the `generated-sources` directory.

Is there a way to tell Maven to make the `build/targetDir/test/...` (trim the path) directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Maven resources plugin does not provide a way to trim the path like you need.  I can think of two ways to solve this.

1. Change whatever is generating the resources so they are in the final directory structure required (e.g. `${project.build.directory}/additional-resources/test/...`) .  That way when the resources plugin copies the structure, it will be what you want.
2. Use ant, via the maven-antrun-plugin.  Ant has a concept of a "flatten mapper" which allows you to configure the target directory structure during the copy.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've used the assembly plugin, but your solutions are also interesting!